# Personal Microsoft accounts only and Enterprise Applications

Tags: azure-active-directory, service-principal

I created and App registrations with "Personal Microsoft accounts only" options
But this application is not showing under Enterprise Applications. Is that expected?

Since this is not showing under Enterprise Applications, i am not able to add this to Entitlemment management Catalog

As you can see i create a App registration with Personal Microsoft accounts only
I dont see **managed application in local directory** option in overview tab
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can have an Enterprise Application in one tenant while the original App Registration is in a different tenant, but not the other way around. If you have the app registration in your tenant you should always see a corresponding enterprise application in that same tenant. Please try searching for the application under "All Applications" and remove any of the automatically applied filters.

[image]

Try copying the application ID from the App Registration and searching for it in the Enterprise Applications blade (without any filters applied):

[image]

If you post a screenshot of what you see and in each spot while searching for the Application ID and it's still not there, I will raise a bug.

Comment: Added screen shots

Comment: Does it change if you remove the Application Status filter or search in the legacy experience?

Comment: Is the same even if we search in legacy. Raised a Service request with MSFT and they confirmed that for Personal account type, Service principal is not created and hence it cannot be searched in Enterprise application. Is your understanding different?